# "straight out" means the same thing as "in a straight line"?

Tags: meaning, idiomatic-language

> The bristles protruded straight out of the head of the cleaner.
>
> The bristles protruded in a straight line out of the head of the
> cleaner.

[image]

I want to know if they both means the same thing or not and what would be the difference and if both are grammatical.

Comment: I think "straight [out]" here means *perpendicular / at right angles to the **surface** that the bristles are attached to.* Since what the bristles are attached to is effectively a ***pole***, that means the bristles stick out "vertically"  from every point where they're attached to the handle. It wouldn't make much sense to talk about "straight **lines**" in this exact context, because *every* bristle leaves the surface of the pole at a slightly different angle to every other bristle. Approximately, the bristles ***radiate out*** from a central "point" (the "brush head").

Comment: _In a straight line_ would suggest to me that the bristles are all in  a single line - - - - -, which obviously doesn't make sense (though it would be fine for objects placed in a row).

Comment: It would be an unusual brush where they did not lie perpendicular to the surface they were fixed to so it is not clear why either version is needed.